# How to access the Chart object in Javascript DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am drawing charts using chart.js. I am doing this dynamically and hence not storing the Chart objects in any Javascript variables and directly just rendering the charts at the run-time. Now I am thinking to build a feature for updating these charts. I know that for updating the charts, we need to use the `.update()` function. But I am not able to figure out how do I fetch the chart object.

Note: There are many charts on the webpage and new ones are constantly getting added with time. So it is not possible to store the chart objects for my implementation.

Comment: See if you can use "refs" to keep track of each chart and update them accordingly.

Comment: What is "refs"? Can you please share any articles or other resource.

Comment: Either [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) if you're using react or just a plain old getElementById() for vanilla JavaScript. Add ID's to each chart and then you can retrieve each singular instance using those IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the chart instance, you can simply use `Chart.instances` which will return a key-value pair. Values containing the chart instance.
You can refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkq5Lq8b/) as reference.